# Edit form input with javascript before adding to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic rails form like this:

```
<%= form_for @song do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

There are other fields as well, but only this one is relevant. I want to be able to input youtube links, but I want the embed link to be stored in the database. I have a javascript function that converts the regular link to the embed link, so how do I run this function on the input before submission?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does it need to be done with JavaScript? It in no way ensures the URL stored in the database will be the embed URL.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be javascript. I just want to be able to input regular youtube links and store embed links. Unless youtube drastically changes their URL format, I think the conversion will always work.

Comment: I would advise you to do the conversion on the server side. You can use ActiveRecord callbacks to make sure the conversion occurs. The user might not have JavaScript enabled, in those cases no conversion would happen.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. I don't have much web dev experience, so that flew right over my head. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to register a handler for the submit event on the form:

```
$('form#new_song').on('submit', function() {
  field = $(this).find('input#url');

  field.val(conversion_function(field.val()));
});
```